# How to compare one table with name

Tags: kotlin

Hi i have a searchbar on maps and I want it to compare when I search for a city if it is in my City Table

I wrote a Dao and a method for this but every time when I write a wrote a city that doesn't exist the apps crashed`

My data serviceinterface

```
fun getCitiesFindbyName(name: String, getName: GetName)

   fun startBtn(view: View){

        lateinit var location: String
        val dataService: DataService = (requireActivity().application as MyApp).dataService
        val searchView = view.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.sv_location)
        location = searchView.query.toString()
        dataService.getCitiesFindbyName(location, this)
```

the callback

```
interface GetName {

    fun onFinish( city: City)

}
```

and the dao

```
@Query ("SELECT * FROM City WHERE name = :name")
    fun getCitybyId(name:String):City
```

and the map view fragment

```
fun startBtn(view: View){

        lateinit var location: String
        val dataService: DataService = (requireActivity().application as MyApp).dataService
        val searchView = view.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.sv_location)
        location = searchView.query.toString()
        dataService.getCitiesFindbyName(location, this)


    override fun onFinish(city:City ) {
        val dataService: DataService = (requireActivity().application as MyApp).dataService


        if (city.name.isNotEmpty()){
            val latLng = LatLng(city.coord.lat!!, city.coord.lon!!)
            val lat= (city.coord.lat)
            val long = (city.coord.lon)
            val name =(city.name)


            nMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(city.name))
            retrofitResponse2(lat,long,city.name)
            nMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
            dataService.getCitiesFindbyName(name, this)

        }


        else{
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "There is no info about this city", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the crash, or at least the exception message?

Comment: 021-01-10 21:15:55.060 9288-9288/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-01-10 21:15:55.067 9288-9288/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.projekt1rain, PID: 9288
    java.lang.NullPointerException: result must not be null
sCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)

Comment: override fun getCitiesFindbyName(name: String,getName: GetName) {
        val runner = TaskRunner()
        runner.executeAsync({
            val getCitiesbyName = dataBase.currentWeatherDao().getCitybyId(name)
            getCitiesbyName
        }, { result  -> getName.onFinish(result)})

    }